# post id with url using ajax

Tags: ajax, codeigniter-3

```js
im write ajax code in post url and my userid bt not respond that code

<script>

function InviteLink( id, url ){
    console.log(id);
    $.ajax({
      url: https://abc.hrm.com/auth/login
      data: { 'id' : id },      
      success: function(data) {
      }
      });
} 

</script>
```

```html
<button  onclick="InviteLink('<?php echo $employees->fldUserID; ?>','<?php echo base_url($employee_url); ?>');" style="background-color:#00C292; color:white;  font-weight: bold; margin:5px 0px;" title="Invite New Employee" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#invitelink" type="button" class="btn btn-teal btn-circle"><i class="notika-icon notika-mail"></i></button>
```

**front UI in button i write onclick function and get id and url.... but there are not post in my url please help me solve my problem **

Answer (score 0):

You Have to add method type = "POST" in ajax Like Below

```
    <script>
   function InviteLink( id, url ){
    console.log(id);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: https://abc.hrm.com/auth/login,
      data: { 'id' : id },      
      success: function(data) {
      }
      });
} 
    </script>
```